# Print button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here's my code :

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="mytable" >
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Print</th>
        </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initButtonPrint(){
            var button = document.getElementById('button-print');
            button.onclick = function(e){
            print();
            grayLine(1);
                return false; 
            }
        }

        function grayLine(lineId){
            var arrayLine = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
            arrayLine[lineId].style.backgroundColor = "silver";
        }
    </script> 

</thead>   
<tbody>
<br/>

    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$lineNumber; $i++) 
    { 
    ?> 
    <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 2']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="button-print" value="Print"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
    ?>

</tbody>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    initButtonPrint();
    </script>
```

What this code does ?

I put my data from a database into a html table using a for loop and I put a print button in each line. When I click the first print button, the print configuration page opens and the first line is colored grey

```
arrayLine[lineId].style.backgroundColor = "silver";
```

What I want to do ?

When I click on a print button, the line is colored grey (or silver here)

The main issue is that I don't know how to tell the javascript which button from which line was pressed. In my code the first line is colored grey because I passed the number 1 into the function

```
grayLine(1)
```

Another main issue is that only the first print button from the first line works (only one which opens the print configuration page)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: wht dont you call grayLine from your html using onclick ?? <input type="button" id="button-print" value="Print" onclick="grayLine(?php $i ?)"/>

Comment: the id used for button is not unique; hence you will not get which button you clicked. try using button_print_$i as id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I manage to solve my problem and it is ridiculously simple : I deleted the initButtonPrint() and grayLine(lineId) functions which were useless and instead I did this using jQuery (thanks to Gurpreet Janjua) :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-print').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background','grey');
        print();
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem was that I declared my button with id instead of class.

Big thank you to Sun Liren, N Muhammed Thamjeed and everyone who replied to me

Answer (score 0):

may be it's help you :

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="mytable" >
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Print</th>
        </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
<br/>

    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$lineNumber; $i++) 
    { 
    ?> 
    <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 2']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="button-print" value="Print"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
    ?>

</tbody>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-print').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background','grey');
    });
});
</script>
```

in this code,when you click on print button then that row background will be grey..

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works indeed but only for the first button

Comment: use button-print as class not id... then it works for all button

Answer (score 0):

For a quick look, you can see this codepen 
http://codepen.io/SLRXXX/pen/KrmRgE?editors=1111

The attribute 'id' means there's only **one** specific element with the id  in the html DOM tree. So, in the html that you show us, there are many buttons with the same id, which is an improper way to use 'id', but the browser won't tell you. When you use the document.getElementById method, it only returns the first button.
So, what we should do is to bind event to **every** button in the table rows, when button clicked, find the row containing the button (in another word, look for the button's parent table row), then change its color.
To select all the buttons, we can use class instead of id attribute. Or if the page is simple enough, we can just use input[type="button"] to select.

Put the following script **under** your table element.

```
function initButtonPrint() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable .button-print');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons.item(i).onclick = function () {
            var t = this;
            while (true) {           // find the row containing the button
                t = t.parentElement;
                if (t.nodeName === 'TR') {
                    break;
                }
            }
            t.style.backgroundColor = "silver";
        };
    }
}
initButtonPrint();
```

As for your table, it may look like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="mytable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Print</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$lineNumber; $i++) { 
    ?> 
        <tr>        
            <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mytable[$i]['Data']['Column 2']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="button-print" value="Print"/></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, the buttons don't respond.

Comment: I'm sorry there are some mistakes in my code. I made some changes just now, this time I think it will be OK.

Comment: The problem is my print buttons have to be in the for loop because when the user will make a new entry in the database, a new print button needs to be created. I think that's why your solution doesn't work in my code because I have just one <tr>

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `id='button-print'` to `class='button-print'` because 'id' is unique in a document, the loop creat more than one id 

please try the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<table class="table table-hover" id="mytable" >
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Print</th>
        </tr>

</thead>   
<tbody>
<br/>

    <?php

    $database = array(
      'one' => array('name' => 'john' , 'city' => 'noida' , 'addr' => 'xyz','mail' => 'john@xyz.com'),
      'two' => array('name' => 'jimi' , 'city' => 'india' , 'addr' => 'abc','mail' => 'jimi@abc.com'),
      'three' => array('name' => 'foo' , 'city' => 'china' , 'addr' => 'pqr','mail' => 'foo@pqr.com'),
      'four' => array('name' => 'apple' , 'city' => 'america' , 'addr' => 'lmno','mail' => 'apple@lmno.com'),
      );

    foreach($database as $row) 
    { 
    ?> 
    <tr>        
        <td>Name : <?php echo $row['name'];  ?></td>
        <td>City : <?php echo $row['city'];  ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="change_color(this);" class="button-print" value="Print"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</tbody>
</table>
<script>

    function change_color(obj){
        $('.button-print').parent().parent().css('background-color' , 'white');
        $(obj).parent().parent().css('background-color' , 'silver');
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but in my code my database is actually much more complicated than it appears in my question so I cannot try your solution

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sun Liren answer and you should accept it but I would also like to point out the title is somewhat misleading and could be reworded to show what you actually wanted to know( make the buttonclick aware of the row he is a child of). I would also remove the php tag since it's not relevant to the question and I would use dummy data instead of your php code to populate it, to make it easier to get your code to work on tools like jsfiddle. Sorry if that sounded arrogant, it wasn't my intention. Would have posted it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: No problem, i'm new here thanks for your reply I'll be more careful next time.